# emacs customize-face color

Tags: emacs, colors, customization, font-lock, emacs-faces

I tried to customize my emacs color by changing font-lock faces' color (M-x customize-face).
But I found that the amount of color is not as many as all the values #xxxxxx.
For example, when changing a color value from #000000 to #FF0000, I just got only two color, 'red' and a 'lighter red'.

Is this the limit of emacs or I need to use another way to express color value?

Comment: You are using Emacs in a terminal window?

Comment: Yes, I use Emacs on Windows 7 cmd, emacs -nw

Comment: So, without ever having touched a windows shell: Does it allow for 256 colors or more? The symptoms you are describing sound like a terminal that doesn't really support colors.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently a Windows shell doesn't support colors. Either get a modern shell or run in Window mode.